# Using JS to append REST data to a Matrix Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

I have created a Grid/Matrix that I want to append JSON data I gather from a SharePoint list via Fetch.

To each square I applied an ID so items can be appended. I got to this point where I had a brain fart, and can't figure out how to actually input/append the data. I don't want just text over the square, I was thinking with `(::before and ::after)` pseudo elements when I hover over the square where an event is, a modal or dialog will pop up containing information about the event.

The data I am pulling through fetch, is formatted as JSON in data.d.results.

Here is a sample of the data

JSON RESPONSE

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "Title": "Pandemic & Natural Disasters",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(2)",
        "Likelihood": "5",
        "Consequence": "3"
      },
      {
        "Title": "New Example",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(3)",
        "Likelihood": "4",
        "Consequence": "4"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Example #2",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(3) Performance (Scope)",
        "Likelihood": "4",
        "Consequence": "3"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Delays",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(2) Schedule",
        "Likelihood": "5",
        "Consequence": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the grid is a 5x5, and where the dialog/modal will go is based on the data values Likelihood(Y-Axis), and Consequence(X-Axis). So in the sample data x=3, y=4 so it would be in the yellow square. Then inside of the dialog/modal the text should display as follows:

```
-------------------------------------
|               Title               |
|              Category             |
|              Priority             |
|               Status              |
|              Severity       
|
------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Here is my matrix:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 60px 0 90px 90px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
p.likelihood {
   transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
   transform-origin: top;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: -20px;
   font-size: 30px;
   margin: 0;
}

p.consequence {
   font-size: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   left: calc(50% + 45px);
   bottom: -60px;
   margin: 0;
}

.numbers-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.numbers-container-x {
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: -25px; 
}

.numbers-container-x .number {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers-container-y {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0;
}

.numbers-container-y .number {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1" id="5" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="4" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="6" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div> 
    <div class="box box1" id="7" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="8" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="9" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="10" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="15"  style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="14" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="13" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="12" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="11" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="16" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="17" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="18" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="19" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="20" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="25" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="24" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="23" style="background-color: #ff3232;">


    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="22" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="21" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-y">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-x">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
  </div>
  
  <p class="likelihood">
    Likelihood
  </p>
  <p class="consequence">
    Consequence
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: I do not properly understand the question. I think for better understanding you could provide some test case that's failing and explain what the result should be. Screenshots of what the problematic behavior is and what the expected behavior is would help a lot as well.

Comment: Is it an option to modify the DOM structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible, you could make it easier for you by modifying your DOM structure by following this template and having 5 rows that contains 5 boxes:

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can easily then in JavaScript to get the corresponding box node by using this function:

```js
const getBoxNode = (x, y) => {
  const rowId = Math.abs(y - 5)
  const row = document.querySelector(`.row:nth-child(${rowId + 1})`)

  return row.querySelector(`.box:nth-child(${x})`)
}
```

You can then just add the data to this node:

```js
const appendData = (data) => {
  const {Title, category, Priority, Status, Severity} = data
  const x = data.consequence
  const y = data.likelihood

  const box = getBoxNode(x, y);
  
  // add texts
  [Title, category, Priority, Status, Severity].forEach((text) => {
    const pNode = document.createElement('p')
    pNode.textContent = text
    
    box.appendChild(pNode)
  })
}
```

Here the complete code:

```js
const risks = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
        "Title": "Pandemic & Natural Disasters",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(2)",
        "Likelihood": "5",
        "Consequence": "3"
      },
      {
        "Title": "New Example",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(3)",
        "Likelihood": "4",
        "Consequence": "4"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Example #2",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(3) Performance (Scope)",
        "Likelihood": "4",
        "Consequence": "3"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Delays",
        "Status": "Active",
        "Priority": "(1) High",
        "Category": "(2) Schedule",
        "Likelihood": "5",
        "Consequence": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}




const getBoxNode = (x, y) => {
  const rowId = Math.abs(y - 5)
  const row = document.querySelector(`.row:nth-child(${rowId + 1})`)

  return row.querySelector(`.box:nth-child(${x})`)
}

const appendData = (item) => {
  const {
    Title,
    Category,
    Priority,
    Status,
    Severity
  } = item
  const x = Number(item.Consequence)
  const y = Number(item.Likelihood)

  const box = getBoxNode(x, y);

  // add texts
  [Title, Category, Priority, Status, Severity].forEach((text) => {
    const pNode = document.createElement('p')
    pNode.textContent = text

    box.appendChild(pNode)
  })
}

Promise.resolve(risks)
  .then((data) => {
    data.d.results.forEach((item) => {
      appendData(item)
    });
  });
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 60px 0 90px 90px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

p.likelihood {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform-origin: top;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

p.consequence {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: calc(50% + 45px);
  bottom: -60px;
  margin: 0;
}

.numbers-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.numbers-container-x {
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.numbers-container-x .number {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers-container-y {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0;
}

.numbers-container-y .number {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-y">
      <div class="number">1</div>
      <div class="number">2</div>
      <div class="number">3</div>
      <div class="number">4</div>
      <div class="number">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-x">
      <div class="number">1</div>
      <div class="number">2</div>
      <div class="number">3</div>
      <div class="number">4</div>
      <div class="number">5</div>
    </div>

    <p class="likelihood">
      Likelihood
    </p>
    <p class="consequence">
      Consequence
    </p>
</section>
```

Checkout the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn81jfLv/4/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please see my fiddle attached to this comment. Your answer was the closest to what I am trying to do. After I initialize a new fetch request called risks, I  `let items = data.d.results` in fetch(risks) followed by ```items.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item.Title, item.Category, item.Status, item.Priority, item.Likelihood, item.Consequence, item.Severity);
        });```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/kq58un32/1/ in the console after I implemented it, it tells me @ line 19 ```Cannot destructure property 'Title' of 'items' as it is undefined.
    at appendData```

Comment: @BeerusDev That's normal because I also updated the structure of your HTML to give it more logic by adding some `.row` wrapper. So please take into consideration the changes made to the HTML and also the CSS.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I am confused. Do I need to set the type of the Title to ?string?

Comment: In your fiddle your are adding a parameter `items` to the `appendData` function, However when you call it using `appendData()` you don't provide any parameter so `items` is `undefined` and you can't get `Title` out of it.

Comment: I updated my fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/kq58un32/5/ now it is telling me on the SP site when I try implementing it that ```Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined```. How is items not defined, that is where I am confused

Comment: I let items = data.d.results then did a forEach over it. What am I missing?  A return value?

Comment: @BeerusDev **(1)** I checked the code in your JSFiddle and you have some of your `item` logic outside of the `forEach()` loop that initializes `item`. I moved it back inside the loop and resolved that bug. **(2)** Some of the casing was different for the properties in your `fetch()` call and the properties in the sample object you created (e.g. `Category` vs. `category`) https://jsfiddle.net/brandonmcconnell/bfhkso1m/7/

Comment: @BeerusDev I update my example to add a Promise base structure (thanks [@BrandonMcConnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824249/brandon-mcconnell)). Be aware of what you modify in the code, at some point your replaced `item` with `items` that causes troubles.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell it tells me that  ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items.forEach is not a function```. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/t7bqp2o1/3/

Comment: It's really hard for me to help you here since I have no clue what your API exactly return. Here I assume that when you do `let items = data.d.results;`, items is not an array. Try to check what the structure of `data.d.results` is.

Comment: My answer here tell you how to make it works when you have a clean data structure like `risks`. You have then by you own be sure that you get such data. I can't help more without more infos.

Comment: @johannchopin the structure of data.d.results is JSON. Here is a fiddle that include my new request as well as the rest of my JS. I can't pull from the actual SharePoint list/api as it is behind a protected firewall. https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/y2nj34o6/2/

Comment: @BeerusDev Please share what `response.json()` give back in your promise I can't guess it :/

Comment: @BeerusDev I don't see that error. I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: webAppUrl is not defined"

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell I change my url a bit. The list is behind a strict firewall so no one has authentication to access it outside.

Comment: @johannchopin please see my most recent edit I added my response.json

Comment: @BeerusDev I updated my code with the full JSON response, it hopefully also works on your side now :) If it does please don't forget to attribute the bounty it's not done automatically.

Comment: I will award the bounty, but it does not work? It keeps telling me results is undefined. What is wrong with my JS? It should work fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/awg49k63/1/ Please see my JS @johannchopin

Comment: On line 14 you have an extra `Promise.resolve(risks)`, I guess you have to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already fetching the data - so it means you are using javascript. In that case you may use `title` attribute to show the info as a tooltip. To simplify the way you may look for specific cell, you may want to change the `id`s so it would be easier to find the right one.

Here is an example with the data you provided. Hover on top of [4,3] element & you'll see the tooltip with the data.

```js
const dataFromFetch = {
  "likelihood" : 4, 
  "consequence": 3, 
  "severity" : 12, 
  "category": "Category Name", 
  "Status": "Active", 
  "Title": "This is the Title of the Occurrence", 
  "Priority": "High"
}

document.getElementById( dataFromFetch.likelihood + '-' + dataFromFetch.consequence ).title =  
  dataFromFetch.category + '\n' + 
  dataFromFetch.Status + '\n' + 
  dataFromFetch.Title + '\n' +
  dataFromFetch.Priority
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 60px 0 90px 90px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
p.likelihood {
   transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
   transform-origin: top;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: -20px;
   font-size: 30px;
   margin: 0;
}

p.consequence {
   font-size: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   left: calc(50% + 45px);
   bottom: -60px;
   margin: 0;
}

.numbers-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}

.numbers-container-x {
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: -25px; 
}

.numbers-container-x .number {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers-container-y {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0;
}

.numbers-container-y .number {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1" id="5-1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="4-1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3-1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2-1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1-1" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">
    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="5-2" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div> 
    <div class="box box1" id="4-2" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3-2" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2-2" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1-2" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="5-3"  style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="4-3" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3-3" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2-3" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1-3" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="5-4" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="4-4" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3-4" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2-4" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1-4" style="background-color: 
  #329932;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="5-5" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="4-5" style="background-color: #ff3232;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="3-5" style="background-color: #ff3232;">


    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="2-5" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
    <div class="box box1" id="1-5" style="background-color: #ffff32;">

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-y">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="numbers-container numbers-container-x">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
  </div>
  
  <p class="likelihood">
    Likelihood
  </p>
  <p class="consequence">
    Consequence
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: I really like the tooltip! You learn something new everyday! How could I have something pop up in the box to indicate that something is there?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/z6v5a29q/1/ see my fiddle. I tried this method, and I am given an error in the console: ```Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: item is not defined```